# Segmentation of hand drawn logic gates in image

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

Input hand drawn logical gate

[image]

[image]

I want to separate the gates from the circuit so that I can run on the isolated Svm images and can detect the type of gates but my problem here is how can I detect or segment the gates in the circuit?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach to isolate the logic gates. The idea is to use `cv2.HoughLinesP()` for line detection. Once we have the detected lines, we effectively remove the lines on a mask to isolate the gates. From here, we perform morphological operations to clean the image and obtain a single contour from each gate. Finally, we perform contour filtering and ROI extraction

---

Detected lines to remove

[image]

Results

[image]

Extracted ROIs

[image]

Depending on the input image, you may have to change the parameters in `cv2.HoughLinesP()` and the minimum threshold area. With `maxLineGap=50` and `area > 1000`, here's the results with the other input image

[image]

I implemented this approach in Python OpenCV

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Grayscale + Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
original = image.copy()
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find lines
minLineLength = 10
maxLineGap = 150
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(thresh,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv2.line(thresh,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,0),5)

# Morphological operations to clean image
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (9,9))
close  = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=3)
cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

# Contour filtering and ROI extraction
ROI_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 3000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ROI = original[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (36, 255, 12), 8)
        ROI_number += 1

cv2.imwrite('thresh.png', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('close.png', close)
cv2.imwrite('image.png', image)
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer , but in many cases The lines are not as straightforward as this, some lines are very complex and skewed

Comment: Could you add the image to the post? As long as it is a line it should work (no curves)

Comment: I mean, if these circuits are handwritten, the lines may not be as smooth as the image above ...   look at this image [ https://ibb.co/M6MVRbm ]

Comment: You may have to change the parameters in houghLinesP and the contour area threshold. I get a good result with `maxLineGap=50` and `area > 1000`

Comment: I used svm for recognition but I didn't know what to do for detection

Comment: You should probably open a new question for that

Comment: I implemented this code in Emgucv V4 but the result I got is very different from your result and not at all satisfactory, do you think the problem with Emgucv?

Comment: You can use the same approach but unfortunately I'm not familiar with Emgucv

Comment: I did exactly that, but the output of the hough line function would find over a thousand lines and curves but what I was expecting to find was just lines, so I say the Houghline function in Emgucv doesn't work like Python Okay

Comment: Yes its probably implemented differently so that resulting output may not be the same